# how to get the values from GET url in Coldfusion and pass them to your query?

Tags: url, coldfusion

I'm working on project where I have to search for first, last name, email and building. If I enter any letter in the one of these four boxes I should limit my query on that URL parameter. I already have created my query that creates XML output for entire table.

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><cfsilent>
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="Customers">
    Select Email, FirstName, LastName, d.BuildingName, Active
    From Customers s Join Building d
    On s.Building = d.Building
    Where Active > 0 and FirstName = %something% or LastName = %something% or Email = %something% or BuildingName = %something%
</cfquery>
<cfsetting showDebugOutput="No">
<!--- These are standard elements which can be inserted back into a request --->
</cfsilent>
<livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name"><cfoutput query="myQuery">
<customer>
    <customer_id>#XMLFormat(BuildingName)#</customer_id>
    <first_name>#XMLFormat(FirstName)#</first_name>
    <last_name>#XMLFormat(LastName)#</last_name>
    <email>#XMLFormat(Email)#</email>
</customer></cfoutput>
</livelookup>
```

Comment: One thing at a time.  Does your cfldap tag return any data?

Comment: No, I did not get any data back. I never used this tag before and I do not know where my query should be.

Comment: You should take some time to learn more about ColdFusion: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/ is a great starting point. Lots of good examples and explanation covering a lot of topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new question, here is how you get your data.

```
 where firstName = <cfqueryparam 
                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
                   value = "#url.firstname#">
```

etc.

Still on the one step at a time theme, it's a good idea to get the sql, coldfusion, whatever stuff working properly before worrying about formatting the results.